# Order items by name then by parent

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table that has a list of settings that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `widget_settings` (
    `setting_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `widget_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `setting_parent` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `setting_name` CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `setting_type` CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `setting_default` CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`setting_id`)
)
```

I would like to order the the rows by `setting_name`, and some of the settings have children, so after the setting list it's children, and children have the name `setting_parent`, so basically I want output that would look like this:

```
setting_name       | setting_id      | setting_parent
-------------------------------------------------------
A                  | 1               | 0
B                  | 2               | 0
YA                 | 4               | 2
YB                 | 5               | 2
C                  | 20              | 0
ZA                 | 25              | 20
```

I was hoping that this would work, but it doesn't:

```
select * from widget_settings 
where widget_id = 1
order by setting_name, setting_parent
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1a123)

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of levels for parent child within the data.  So B has Z1 and Z2 could Z1 have Y1 and Y1 have X1 or does it only go 1 level deep? if there's a limit to the levels, I think this can be done with mySQL, if not then dynamic SQL would be needed I believe as MySQL doesn't support hiericharical queries or recursive queries to my knowledge which I think  are needed to do this...

Comment: For now, I think one level deep is enough, and if 2 is possible that would be cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.*
from widget_settings a
left join widget_settings b
  on b.widget_id = a.widget_id
  and b.setting_id = a.setting_parent
where a.widget_id = 1
order by 
  ifnull(b.setting_name, a.setting_name),
  if(b.setting_name is null, '', a.setting_name)
```

Test on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1a123/5)

Here how `order by` is constructed:

```
A  ''
B  ''
B  YA   <-- parent name goes to first position & children name to second
B  YB
C  ''
C  ZA
```

Comment: I think I was able to get three levels, visually it works so far! So thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for one level.  The concept could apply for N levels but each adds a left join. and complicates the order by further.

It basically joins widget_Settings to itself and concats the the parent name to the child.  For example:

Setting_ID 2,4, 5 would become

```
B -   2
BYA - 4
BYB - 5
```

This is untested however...

```
SELECT P.setting_Name, P.Setting_Id, P.Setting_parent
FROM widget_Settings P
LEFT JOIN widget_Settings C
 on C.Setting_Parent = P.Setting_ID
ORDER BY CONCAT(P.Setting_name,coalesce(C.Setting_name,''))
```

Comment: with that fiddle, the first one is "action" which is correct, but the second one should be "test" since it's parent is `2`, then should come "wrapper", but that one is last and there is 2 of them for some reason.